# Generate invoice even if product is pending or disable

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, invoice, order-status

After order is placed, if product status change to `disable` or `Pending` its not possible to generate invoice.

How to generate invoice even if product is `pending` or `disable` without changing status of product?

Comment: huh? How does the product become disabled after placing an order? or `pending` ?

Comment: Here is a case, customer care executive change status of product (so many reasons for this, like price change or supplier complaint or product is faulty or any other concern ) and approval is pending for admin, but in mean time operation executive want to generate invoice of old order where this same product is part of it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by `pending` as a product status, it can simply be Enabled or Disabled.

Regardless of the status of the product, you are still able to invoice the order running Magento CE 1.7.0.2. Magento stores order & invoice information in flat tables which do not care for many EAV attributes.

Even if you deleted the product, Magento would still be able to invoice the order, because it pulls the product info (pricing etc) from `sales_flat_order` & `sales_flat_order_item`.

Think about it in this way, if you sell product a, b, and c this year. In 5 years from now, you may not even have them listed on your website anymore, i.e have deleted them. That doesn't mean you still wouldn't want them on your order records, hence the storage in flat tables.